# Ansible retrieve the value of keys from the other list

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

I've the json with below list of unique keys.

```
{
    "image_names": [
        {
            "name": "sles-11-factory-os-ready"
        },
        {
            "name": "sles-11-factory-base-vg00"
        },
        {
            "name": "sles-11-factory-base"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-7-factory-os-ready"
        },
        {
            "name": "sles-12-factory-os-ready"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-6-factory-os-ready"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-7-factory-base-vg00"
        },
        {
            "name": "sles-12-factory-base-vg00"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-6-factory-base-vg00"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-7-factory-base"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel-6-factory-base"
        },
        {
            "name": "sles-12-factory-base"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've another json with the above keys but having different values.

```
{
  "rhel-7-factory-os-ready" : [
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      }
   ],
   "rhel-6-factory-os-ready" : [
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
          "updated": "2019-05-07T15:51:00Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the oldest images by their updated datetime values by iterating through each image. Eventually, I'm expecting the below dataset of old images when sorted by `updated` field of `rhel-6-factory-base` image

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'updated': u'2019-05-07T15:20:39Z', 'name': u'rhel-6-factory-base', 'id': u'30109a53-4aab-4fb5-87ff-7650e75731b0'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'updated': u'2019-05-07T12:21:36Z', 'name': u'rhel-6-factory-base', 'id': u'294821b3-e9df-4b12-ae39-8deb8f9c72ff'}) => {
    "msg": "The images to be deleted are: 294821b3-e9df-4b12-ae39-8deb8f9c72ff"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'updated': u'2019-04-29T14:04:20Z', 'name': u'rhel-6-factory-base', 'id': u'068ae5f0-d7a0-4419-829e-18eb25551c94'}) => {
    "msg": "The images to be deleted are: 068ae5f0-d7a0-4419-829e-18eb25551c94"
}
```

I've tried with below ansible but no luck!

```
- name: Print the old images
    debug:
      msg: "The images to be deleted are: {{ item.id }}"
    when:
      - item|length > 1
      - index != 0
      - item.id is defined
#    loop: "{{ grouped_by_name['rhel-6-factory-base'] }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ image_names | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
      - grouped_by_name
    loop_control:
      index_var: index
```

In the above snippet, `image_names` & `grouped_by_name` vars are the first two datasets respectively.

How could I do the dual loop of `grouped_by_name` from the keys passed by `image_names` var?

In case if the question isn't clear, please feel free to comment, I'll try to rephrase it.

Comment: Do you really need the `image_names` variable? Can't you just use the keys in the second data structure?

Comment: Hi @larsks, I agree with you. There is no need of the `image_names`. That's something I created to ease my life but if you could let me know how I could loop through the json without knowing keys, it would be great. At this point in time, I'm not that good with ansible nested loops :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't actually need a nested loop at all.  Your goal is for each key in the dictionary to find the oldest image.  We can do that like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    images:
      rhel-7-factory-os-ready:
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-04T15:51:00Z'
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-01T15:51:00Z'
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-07T15:51:00Z'
      rhel-6-factory-os-ready:
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-09T15:51:00Z'
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-03T15:51:00Z'
      - id: 79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14
        updated: '2019-05-01T15:51:00Z'
      thing-with-a-single-image:
      - id: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123
        updated: '2019-05-01T15:51:00Z'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          image_name: "{{ item.key }}"
          image_to_delete: "{{ item.value|sort(attribute='updated')|first }}"
      when: item.value|length > 1
      loop: "{{ images|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Then `when` statement there is to make sure we don't delete an image if it is the only item in the list.

This will produce:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=rhel-6-factory-os-ready) => {
    "msg": {
        "image_name": "rhel-6-factory-os-ready",
        "image_to_delete": {
            "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
            "updated": "2019-05-01T15:51:00Z"
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=rhel-7-factory-os-ready) => {
    "msg": {
        "image_name": "rhel-7-factory-os-ready",
        "image_to_delete": {
            "id": "79334504-3e48-4411-b602-afe920e32e14",
            "updated": "2019-05-01T15:51:00Z"
        }
    }
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=thing-with-a-single-image)
```

Comment: `ERROR! 'loop_var' is not a valid attribute for a Task` is the error message. Tried adding `loop_control` too, but didn't help. I know this is a syntax thingy but not sure why it's working

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled "control" as "var".

Comment: With `loop_control` I get this error message. `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}`